# Proper way of structuring different release streams in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am new to Git.
I've used another source repository where we have a single repository with a main stream with all the latest, then as we release a product, we create separate stream for that product version so that I may have streams like:

```
 - main
 - ver1.0
 - ver2.0
```

And they are treated as separate entity and not related.

How do I turn this structure into Git repository?

I was initially thinking of creating a "master" branch in a repository with nothing in it.  Then create a branch called "main" which will have the latest (I could use the "master" as the main instead of creating separate main), then create another branch called "ver1.0" then another branch called "ver2.0" in the repository.

Then on the client side, user will need to create a different work-space for each of these branches.  And when they need to work on tasks, they will create a local branch for the task and push the changes to its remote branch when completed.

It looks like this would work, but then I noticed that in the server, all these branches that I created seem to be related to the master branch and it shows things like how many changes a particular branch is behind or ahead.

I don't know this is a common or proper way of structuring what I want to structure in git.  I sense it probably isn't.  So what would be the proper "git" way of structuring this?

Comment: When you create a new branch do it in an orphan mode. But if you are looking for something that have same roots I would not suggest to "orphanize" them/

Answer (score 0):

Read about git flow it should answer your question.

Git flow is a well designed got flow for release management.
It was first introduced by **Vincent Driessen** and has became the most common git workflow for releasing and management projects.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've seen something like this before.  They all come to master in the end.  I guess what I want is like 3 different master branches inside a single repository.  Maybe I just need to think differently from what I've used to before.

Comment: Exactly or you can have this model duplicate 3 times and have a single repository for combining it when required.

Comment: Tell them how to create orphaned branches.